# Circuit analysis and general study tips

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis

The more work I do in the field of EE, the more I realizing that my general circuit analysis skills are usually the root of my confusion and could use improvement. Even after putting on my break-a-big-problem-into-smaller-pieces hat, I still find myself confused about the relationships between parts (especially when multiple parts share a net).

I'm sure that years of experience down the road will eventually provide this, but I'd like to create a solid foundation sooner than later (and hopefully avoid a lot of the frustration and embarrassment I'm already dealing with).

That being said, my main question is this: **what advice would you have for a focused, targeted studying approach for quickly becoming fluent in circuit analysis?**

I've known people who are similarly aged as me (young) who can cruise through analysis in no time at all, and I too want to work toward having this superpower. Should I start at a modular level and fully understand each component type (i.e. [Make's Encyclopedia of Electronics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449333893)) before moving forward? Should I slowly wade through [the newly revised tome of EE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521809266)? Should I dive into certain types of circuits (e.g. current mirrors, voltage regulators, etc.) to better understand topologies? Is there a resource that compiles a large number of circuit problems that start out very simple and increase in difficulty, accompanied with thorough explanations (sort of like a Khan Academy approach)? I have nearly a dozen books, but most just offer the answer and lack elaborate explanation, so even when I get the answer right I'm still unsure of many aspects.

Another way to look at it: if an arbitrary/tight time limit of, say, 25 hours, was imposed what circuit analysis topics and best practice approaches to studying them would you use?

Thanks for any help with this! My head's spinning and feeling overburdened, so any clarity would be greatly appreciated. (It'll also help alleviate me burdening this forum with a laundry list of questions :) )

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question and that is what SE EE is actually about. Even if a definitive answer on this was apparent, next year it would be out of date. I'm voting to close this question, sorry.

Comment: 1.) Series/parallel networks, voltage/current dividers, and Thevenin/Norton equivalents should be second nature. 2.) Know 1st and 2nd order networks' transient and frequency responses. 3.) Accumulate a "bag of tricks," various circuit topologies for various purposes. Reading intuitive books (e.g., Camenzind "Designing Analog Chips") is the best approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

I went through exactly the same struggle you did.  My first circuits class was the hardest one I had taken up to that point.  Now I'm a professional Analog IC design engineer so it is possible to learn this stuff.  In my opinion Horowitz and Hill is highly overrated and people who read it *think* they understand electronics.  I've had much more luck with [Sedra and Smith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195323033) and [Introduction to Electronic Circuit Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201361833)

To become a good circuit designer (and analyzer) you really need to get a grip on the rules of thumb and how to analyze circuits quickly.  I very rarely write a bunch of node equations and solve them any more.  The Introduction to Electronic Circuit Design is especially good because it teaches you how to recognize common circuit blocks and how to quickly get their gain, input/output impedance etc without doing a bunch of algebra.

If I were you, I would focus on learning the rules of thumb and solving as many circuits are you can, over and over.  Then go back and learn more detailed theory to fill in the holes when you need it.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd have to say that Horowitz provides a vague working knowledge. Such as "Do it like this, and this is what it can do". But to understand it (how and when), or even to change it to satisfy a different output, will probably require a more indepth knowledge and that would be where Sedra & Smith come in. I use both books, but I use them to compliment each other. Sedra is very technical and math driven. Horowitz is, here's a cool a circuit with some rules of thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

I can talk only in an academic point of view.I feel that the most crucial part in understanding and be fluent in circuit analysis is the "component" "state" "model" approach.i.e you should be knowing the active and passive components .Its simple as there are only a few of them .RLC V source and I Source .Then you should know the nodal and mesh analysis (KCL and KVL).Then you should study what is transient and steady state and how the components behave in each case.Practice some problems on pulse shaping using these components .Then comes the concept of junctions and how uni junction and multi junction devices deals slow varying and fast varying wave forms .Here also the concept of RLC will help(Say mos capacitances ).With addition of term "dynamic" coming in to picture like dynamic resistance .Then study the model of opamp ,and with the knowledge gained so far you will be able to understand concepts like virtual ground and how op amp is used for different applications.once you know how to do level shifting and pulse shaping using op amp ciruits you are half way through .Knowing the   use of PLL and Pulse transformers would  be added advantage .I know its a big list but the beauty of Analog is that it is vast and natural as the Sea :D